# Code-Signing Windows EXE with Sectigo Hardware Token (SafeNet Authentication Client) on Ubuntu 22.04 Using PKCS11 Tools and osslsigncode

Tags: code-signing, pkcs#11, safenet

I am able to sign my Windows EXEs on Windows using SAC and `singtool.exe`. But this requires a Windows machine which I don't have readily available access to. I primarily work on Linux and the Sectigo support folks tell me this process is feasible on Linux but I'm running into issues.

I can run the SAC and see the certificate, etc. I have successfully inspected the certificate using `pkcs11-tool`:

```
pkcs11-tool --module /usr/lib/pkcs11/libeToken.so --login --list-objects
```

I have found several references to `osslsigncode` but yet they all use the certificate and key in the command line.

What tools and/or commands do I use to actually sign the Windows EXE on Ubuntu when the OV certificate bundle and private key are on a hardware token from Sectigo?

Comment: Try to specify path to certificate and private key as URIs like in this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70493029/3868464).

Comment: Thanks @Alexander
I'm using a different tool so I'm not sure how to get that URL. I've been able to get some info that might help but I'm not sure. I'll poke around with your advice in mind.

Comment: have a look at this: [Sign Authenticode files with Osslsigncode on Linux](https://docs.digicert.com/en/software-trust-manager/signing-tools/osslsigncode-with-pkcs11.html). They are using the meintoned URI schema: `-key 'pkcs11:object=<keypair alias>;type=private'`

Comment: What tool are you using?
What it says for `--help`?

Comment: I got it working but it's a mess. I'll update my question with an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up testing various methods using a variety of tools: `pkcs11-tool`, `p11tool`, `p11-kit`. The steps are as follows:

Run `p11tool --provider=/usr/lib/libeTPkcs11.so --list-all`. This should list the actual URIs for the tokens. Other tools only gave URIs for other certificates but not my hardware token.

Next, I had to wrangle with which `pkcs11engine` to use. I tried several mentioned in these posts and elsewhere but got errors. I finally found `pkcs11.so` for one of my snaps:

```
/snap/core22/858/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/engines-3/pkcs11.so
```

Then I had to construct the command line. I started out using only the URI as the key, which didn't work. So I found the certificate ID, `pkcs11cert`, with this command:

```
pkcs11-tool --module /usr/lib/pkcs11/libeToken.so --login --list-objects --id 01
```

The ID was showing up via other command output, but in a form with colons so I wasn't sure how to use it (eg, `ID: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx`).

I finally landed on this command line:

```
osslsigncode sign -askpass -verbose -h sha256 \
-pkcs11engine /snap/core22/858/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/engines-3/pkcs11.so \
-pkcs11module /lib/libeToken.so \
-t http://timestamp.sectigo.com \
-pkcs11cert xxxx \
-key "pkcs11:model=xxxx;manufacturer=xxxx;serial=xxxx;token=xxxx;object=xxxx;type=cert" \
-in /path/to/executable_UNSIGNED.exe \
-out /path/to/executable_LINUX_SIGNED.exe
```

I'm a bit weary of using that snap `pkcs11engine` but it is working. I'll continue to refine this process, but for now I'm satisfied with the progress.

Answer (score 1):

> What tools and/or commands do I use to actually sign the Windows EXE on Ubuntu when the OV certificate bundle and private key are on a hardware token from Sectigo?

You can also use [Jsign](https://ebourg.github.io/jsign/), the syntax looks like this:

```
jsign --storetype ETOKEN --storepass <PIN> -t http://timestamp.sectigo.com application.exe
```

It figures out the location of the SAC PKCS#1 module, and if there is only one key on the token it's selected automatically.

(disclaimer: I'm the author of this project)

Comment: This is a great tip, thhnks. Ever since CAs starting requiring keys and certs on hardware, this has been an issue. I'll take a look at your tool and give it a try.

Comment: I have the same problem as OP.  Trying to sign a windows exe on linux with sectigo hardware token.

I'm trying jsign.  I get 'unsupported file: myexe.exe'

Comment: @sliptonic Could you report this issue to the Jsign project please?